# What is the max length of a public note when attaching it to a bitcoin transaction using blockchain.info?

Tags: blockchain.info, public-note

What is the max length of a public note when using this feature on blockchain.info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling this, my first hit was the [blockchain.info website FAQ](https://blockchain.info/de/wallet/website-faq). Under the point "How do I make a public note?" they show the following picture:

[image: Public Note window]

I'm gonna go out on a limb here, but I think it means that you can put "Anything you like up to **255 characters**." into a public note.